# Nativescript StackView on Listview onClick

Tags: repeater, tap, nativescript

I have this repeater,

```
<Repeater.itemTemplate>          
    <StackLayout tap="tapEvent" index='im-an-index'>
    <Image src="{{src}}" stretch="aspectFill" />
   </StackLayout>
</Repeater.itemTemplate>
```

I want to get the index on my tap event. My JS looks like this,

```
function tapEvent(args) {
    var target = args.object;
  var index = target.index;
    console.log(index);
}
exports.tapEvent = tapEvent;
```

On console.log, I only get {} .. How can I get the index attr of the tapped stacklayout? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there was a bug and in some cases a wrong object is passed to `args.object`. You can try to get the stack with `args.view`.

Comment: Yeahh.. your right. `args.view` solves the problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

We can get the $value from repeater, but is there some $index?